# Strategy to write error free english

Tags: errors, typographical-errors

When I write a document I make different kind of errors. I do check for such errors like running Spelling and Grammar checks using MS Word etc. however many times I catch such error only after I share my writeup to someone. In those cases, I do check my document multiple times but for some reason unknown to me, I notice such error only after I send, and that brings lot of embarrassment for me.

Below is one such examples of my writeup -

> From above discussion, below observations can be made
>
> 1. XXX and YYY are providing competition views in order to make right thing...

As you see in above writeup I actually wanted to write *competing* not *competition*. Interestingly, I ran Word's Spelling and Grammar tool before sharing above write-up, but it failed to catch this error. And, I was only able to catch this just after sending this document.

I am looking for some good strategy how this kind of error can be caught efficiently? Is it common human error? Or I am developing some psychological issue and then what are the ways to address such issue?

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: Don't be a human.

Comment: This looks like it's answered by [How can I catch more errors when I proofread?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/5400/34330) on Writing. (FWIW, "competition views" could be used in some other context, as it's the same grammar as "scenic mountain views".)

Comment: showing your document to someone else to proofread is a great way to catch errors you didn't catch on your own.

Comment: As @Esther. I am a native English speaker with a good education. I can write a document, error-check it, read it over, wait, read it again, and still there can be errors. This isn't really a language question. See [Paris in the the Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_in_the_the_Spring).

Comment: @WeatherVane I am also a native English speaker with a good education, and sometimes you just don't/can't catch your own mistakes, but someone else can. If you have someone else to show it to, that's a great way of fixing mistakes sometimes.

Comment: @Esther thank you, but there was no need to explain what proofreading is.